# Initializer list of RValues

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Right now I have a class with only one constructor

```
ShaderProgram(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<const Shader>> shaders);
```

I'm using a reference wrapper because I can't have an initializer_list of references and I can't copy

This code works

```
    Shader v{ Shader::Type::Vertex, readFile("res/simple.vert") };
    Shader f{ Shader::Type::Fragment, readFile("res/simple.frag") };
    ShaderProgram shader{ v, f };
```

But this does not

```
    ShaderProgram shader{ 
        Shader { Shader::Type::Vertex, readFile("res/simple.vert") },
        Shader { Shader::Type::Fragment, readFile("res/simple.frag") }
    };
```

What should I be covering here? I suppose I'm missing some kind of constructor to handle rvalues but I can't seem to make it work

The current **error** is:

> E1776 function "std::reference_wrapper<_Ty>::reference_wrapper(_Ty &&) [with
>   _Ty=const core::graphics::Shader]" (declared at line 1830 of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits")
>   cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted
>   function  RenderEngine    Main.cpp    (77)

Comment: "This does not work" -- how? What error do you receive? Can you make an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: [Here is a MCVE](https://godbolt.org/g/WjSZkg).  The problem is that `std::reference_wrapper` is specified to have a deleted move-constructor  (don't ask me why)

Comment: In the other question you said that `A` was non-copyable. Is that also true for this question? If so then you should include that info in the question.

Comment: @songyuanyao yes /

Comment: Also explain what `ShaderProgram` constructor actually does with the things in the initializer list. (It can't hold references to them since they are destroyed after the constructor call, and it can't make copies of them since they are non-copyable, that doesn't leave much option)

Comment: @M.M `reference_wrapper<T>` doesn't have a deleted move constructor. It has a deleted constructor from rvalue `T`s because that's unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reference_wrapper` cannot be created from a prvalue. So what you're doing isn't possible.

It seems to me that your interface seems somewhat confused. On the one hand, `Shader` is a non-copyable type. But on the other hand, you seem to want to call `ShaderProgram` with `Shader` prvalues, which will be destroyed immediately after the `ShaderProgram` object is constructed.

I say, have two interfaces for `ShaderProgram`: one that takes an `initializer_list<Shader>`: such users would be uninterested in keeping their `Shader` objects around past the function's initialization. The other would take an array/vector/etc of non-null pointers to `Shader` objects. This would be for those users who want to keep their `Shader` objects around after creating the program.

It's also possible to create a variadic template, where you require that all of the elements are of the `Shader` type. The last part (verifying that all of the types passed are `Shader` of some form) is rather difficult without C++17 features.

Comment: Thanks. The concrete case is that a shader needs to be attached in shaderprogram constructor, and then the shaderptogram needs to link them, after that shaders can be destroyed(but don't need to be). Right now I have the "not destroyed" covered but the inline option that I'm asking would also make sense. About the c++17 features are you talking about concepts? I'm a complete noob with template programming, even more with variadic templates but I will give it a shot

Comment: @PedroDavid: "*About the c++17 features are you talking about concepts*". No; concepts aren't in C++17. I was specifically referring to fold expressions, which would allow you to do this: `static_assert(is_same_v<decay_t<Args>>, Shader> && ... && true, "An argument type is not a Shader.");` Without fold expressions (or `std::conjunction` which is also new in C++17), doing a condition across a parameter pack is really hard.

Comment: (reviving old thread). I just implemented it using a variadic template (without fold expressions). It seems the best option yet! With a usage problem. Now my ShaderProgram is templated and it's cumbersome to pass on around (unless I template a function I have to know exactly how many Shaders the ShaderProgram has...). To avoid that I created a templated friend "make_shader_program" that returns a non templated ShaderProgram, I don't know if this is an "hack" or good practice.

Comment: Also, in questions to implementation, I don't have access to fold expressions yet so I used something like [this](https://youtu.be/CU3VYN6xGzM?t=2m4s). A problem arised, it seems static cast requires a ; (semicolon). I solved it using IIFE in a lambda expression. This seems good and all but it doesn't seem to compile under gcc (parameter pack is not expanded for some reason) so I'm afraid if i'm relaying in undefined behavior or something.

Comment: Another way I found was with 2 parameter pack expansions, one with a custom type trait (static_assert(are_same<Shader, std::decay_t<Args>...>::value);) and other to actually do the work.

But trying to simplify the code I actually came up with another idea. What about using static_cast instead of static_assertion and a custom type_trait? Is this good practice?